# sed or awk, removing curly brackets but only if there are no commas inside brackets

Tags: bash, awk, sed, touch

i have this string:

```
ex00/{ft_strdup.c} ex04/{ft_convert_base.c,ft_convert_base2.c} ex05/{ft_split.c}
```

need to remove with sed the curly brackets if there is no comma inside brackets, so desired output:

```
ex00/ft_strdup.c ex04/{ft_convert_base.c,ft_convert_base2.c} ex05/ft_split.c
```

Comment: Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/{\([^,}]*\)}/\1/g' file
ex00/ft_strdup.c ex04/{ft_convert_base.c,ft_convert_base2.c} ex05/ft_split.c
```

Note that the above will work no matter which characters except `,`, `{`, `}`, or `\n` exist in your file names, e.g. these are all valid file names:

```
$ cat file
ex00/{ft_strdup1.c} ex05/{ft-split.c} ex05/{ft=s&pl#it.c}

$ sed 's/{\([^,}]*\)}/\1/g' file
ex00/ft_strdup1.c ex05/ft-split.c ex05/ft=s&pl#it.c
```

If your file names can contain any of the characters I mentioned above as excluded then ask a new question including those in your sample input/output.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```bash
awk -v RS='{[^}]*}' '
RT{
  if(!sub(/,/,"&",RT)){ gsub(/^{|}$/,"",RT) }
}
{ ORS=RT }
1
END{ print "" }
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/\{([[:alpha:]_.]+)}/\1/g' input_file
touch ex00/ft_strdup.c ex04/{ft_convert_base.c,ft_convert_base2.c} ex05/ft_split.c
```